# Issue with SingInWithRedirect method in angular fire

Tags: angular, firebase, google-chrome

I'm using angular for my application and firebase for the backend. for the login we are using signInWithRedirect() funcion from angular fire. It was working fine but i don't know what happend. when i was testing like what will happen if i i go from calback link(account select page) and the login screen - i did this simultniously for few times. after that when i try to login it goes to the callback and comes back to the login even after the successful request i don't know why this happens.This happens only in my local host and privew channels in firebase and its working well in the staging. when i try the same in firefox and try to login it works for all the environments and it also works well whhen i remove my browser sync data and start my chrome fresh. What i think is it may be the issue with the chrome build which is 117. can any one help me with this

Is there any solution to this issue?